# Cambiar atributo "src" de una imagen en función a evento onclick() con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código HTML para una imagen ya puesta:

```
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AatroxIcon()" src="champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg"/>
```

y quiero que se cuente cada click partiendo desde cero, cambiando la imagen en los click impares a otra imagen (como una especie de toggle) mediante javascript, y que se quede la imagen original en los pares:

```
var Aatrox = document.getElementById("Aatrox");
var Aatroxclicks = 0;

function AatroxIcon() {
    Aatroxclicks = Aatroxclicks + 1;
    if (Aatroxclicks % 2 != 0) {
        Aatroxclicks.setAttribute("src", "selected_champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg");
    }
}
```

El código no me funciona y no sé en qué estoy fallando. Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda. :)

Answer (score 4):

El error es que no puedes setear un atributo para la variable `Aatroxclicks` dado que es un número , tendría que ser a la variable `Aatrox`

```
function AatroxIcon() {
  Aatroxclicks = Aatroxclicks + 1;
  if (Aatroxclicks % 2 != 0) {
     Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "selected_champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg");
  else
      Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg");
 }
```

Comment: Que fallo más tonto, no he colocado bien los nombres, muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 1):

Acá lo logré compañero, estaba colocando mal el nombre de su img, acá me esta funcionando, para los numeros pares deja una imagen y los impares otra.

Saludos!

```js
var Aatrox = document.getElementById("Aatrox");
var Aatroxclicks = 0;

function AatroxIcon() {
    Aatroxclicks = Aatroxclicks + 1;
    if (Aatroxclicks % 2 != 0) {
        Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "http://images.evisos.hn/2014/09/02/cachorros-husky-siberianos-urgente_d75de2f77_3.jpg");
    }else{
      Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "http://cotodelobos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/005-300x211.jpg");
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AatroxIcon()" src="http://cotodelobos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/005-300x211.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Un par de cosas, primero el objeto lo has guardado en la variable Aastrox, pero luego intentas modificar el atributo de Aastroxcliks.
Después, indicas el scr en caso de ser Aastroxcliks impar, pero no par, por lo que fallaría y no cambiaría, además se llaman igual, entiendo que es el mismo.
Otra cosa, veo que usas carpetas de gráficos distintas, "champions/" y luego "selected_champions/", no se si es normal.
He hecho un ejemplo usando dos gráficos distintos, pero sacados de Internet, cambia los dos src por los tuyos.

```js
var Aatrox = document.getElementById("Aatrox");
var Aatroxclicks = 0;

function AatroxIcon() {
    Aatroxclicks = Aatroxclicks + 1;
    if (Aatroxclicks % 2 != 0) {
        Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "https://avatar.leagueoflegends.com/NA/K%C3%A1tar%C3%ADn%C3%A1.png");
    } else {
     Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "http://es.mobafire.com/images/champion/icon/katarina.png");

 }
}
```

```html
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AatroxIcon()" src="http://es.mobafire.com/images/champion/icon/katarina.png"/>
```

Otro tema, si de Aastroxcliks solo usas dos valores (par/impar) y no vas a usar el contador para nada mas, el código seria mas claro si fuera una variable booleana.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var Aatrox = document.getElementById("Aatrox");
var AatroxEsPar = true;

function AatroxIcon() {
    if (AatroxEsPar) Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "https://avatar.leagueoflegends.com/NA/K%C3%A1tar%C3%ADn%C3%A1.png");
    else Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "http://es.mobafire.com/images/champion/icon/katarina.png");
    AatroxEsPar=!AatroxEsPar;
}
```

```html
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AatroxIcon()" src="http://es.mobafire.com/images/champion/icon/katarina.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando un atributo por ejm `data-src` en el cual tengas la imagen original

```
<img id="Aatrox" title="Aatrox" alt="6300" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="AatroxIcon()" src="champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg" data-src="champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg"/>
```

También además `var Aatrox = document.getElementById("Aatrox");` realizarlo dentro de la función o lo realices al final del `html` (cuando el `img` ya existe)

```
function AatroxIcon() {
    var Aatrox = document.getElementById("Aatrox"); // Se coloco aquí
    Aatroxclicks = Aatroxclicks + 1;
    if (Aatroxclicks % 2 != 0) {
        // Cambiar a una imagen cualquiera
        Aatrox.setAttribute("src", [UnaRuta_e_Imagen_Existente]);
    } else {
        // Reestablecer la original
        Aatrox.setAttribute("src", Aatrox.getAttribute("data-src"));
    }
}
```

Para lo que indico como `[UnaRuta_e_Imagen_Existente]` deberá ser desde luego la ruta e imagen a cargarse previamente; ya sea una variable que coloques o una función que la determine dentro de tu universo de las demás imagenes que tengas.

**Nota:**

1. En tu código tienes `Aatroxclicks.setAttribute("src", "selected_champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg");` y `Aatroxclicks` es una variable numérica debió ser `Aatrox.setAttribute("src", "selected_champions/Aatrox_Square_0.jpg");`.